# Is there a event in the Discord API that triggers whenever any message is sent?

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to write a Discord bot which replies to every message in a channel after reading its contents and storing it in a variable. It looks like this:

```
@bot.event
async def whenMessageSent()
    i=readmessage()
    print(i)
#replace WhenMessageSent and ReadMessage with the correct function names.
```

I need to find the correct functions to replace "whenMessageSent" and "ReadMessage" with. I'm using the latest Discord Python API, but none of the documentations could help me with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    i = message.content
    print(i)
```

on_message(message) is the whenMessageSend()

message.content is the readmessage()

Read the [Discord Python API Documentary](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) for more info.

Comment: context please... ATM your answer is up for winning the low-quality post review award 2019!